# listview validation help on client side not work

Tags: asp.net, validation, datasource

inside the list view i put a email validation and validation summary, when i press edit it will not validation on client side. how to make it able to validate on client side

```
<span class="title1">Email Address<span style="margin-left:28px;">:</span></span><span style=" margin-left:100px;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="SecurityAnsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmailAdd") %>' Height="25px" Width="200px"/>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexEmailValid" runat="server" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ControlToValidate="SecurityAnsLabel" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Format" ForeColor="Red" Text="*" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `ValidationGroup` property of all the controls(textbox, regular expression control,the button if there is any) involved in this as same like 'EmailValidate'

Hope this works :)